# How to do c++ unique judgement like std::unordered_set during compile time?

Tags: c++

I wanna see the failure during compile time like static_assert instead of running time.

```
std::unordered_set<std::string> s;
#define insert(set, value)                                                     \
  if (!set.insert(value).second)                                               \
    assert(false);

void init() {
  insert(s, "dog");
  insert(s, "bird");
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible, since the behavior of the `insert()` call won't be known until run-time.

Comment: How can that be possible when the string may be read from user input? Also, don't use macros for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr bool all_unique(std::span<T const> const items)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size() - 1; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < items.size(); ++j)
            if (items[i] == items[j])
                return false;
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    auto constexpr strings1 = std::array<std::string_view,4>{"ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL"};
    static_assert(all_unique<std::string_view>(strings1), "array strings1 not unique");

    auto constexpr strings2 = std::array<std::string_view,5>{"ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL","ABC"};
    static_assert(all_unique<std::string_view>(strings2), "array strings2 not unqiue"); //This line doesn't compile
}
```

Note that this function is kind of expensive - you might want to mark it `consteval` instead of `constexpr`, and provide a runtime version too, because there are some improvements you could make when you aren't constexpr constrained.